# Tab contents are not consuming space, so html tags defined later are not actually rendered after tab contents

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build tabs using pure `HTML` and `CSS`. I've got the tab functionality working, so when you click a tab label the corresponding content shows.

But in my design I've 2 tab areas, 1 for request and 1 for response. For some reason my request seems to overlap the response area, why is this so?

The `<hr>` tag that separates the 2 areas should always be below the request area's shown content.

http://jsfiddle.net/bobbyrne01/pgzt6nbf/

### Current output (content tab) ..

[image: current output content]

### Current output (header tab) ..

[image: current output header]

### Desired output ..

[image: desired output]

html ..

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="left w60">
        <div class="center">
                <h2>Request</h2>

        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <input id="url" placeholder="Request URL .." class="w100" />
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div>
                <select id="method">
                    <option value="0">GET</option>
                    <option value="1">HEAD</option>
                </select>
                <button type="button" id="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div class="tabs">
                <div class="tab">
                    <input type="radio" id="tab-1a" name="tab-group-1" hidden checked />
                    <label class="tabLabel" for="tab-1a">Headers</label>
                    <div class="content">
                        <div id="headersRequest">
                            <table id="headersRequestTable" class="w100">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Value</th>
                                    <th>
                                        <input type="button" id="newHeaderButton" value="+" />
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab">
                    <input type="radio" id="tab-2a" name="tab-group-1" hidden checked />
                    <label class="tabLabel" for="tab-2a">Body content</label>
                    <div class="content">
                        <div id="bodyRequest">
                            <textarea id="bodyRequestListItem" rows="10" class="w100"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="center">
                <h2>Response</h2>

        </div>
        <div class="tabs">
            <div class="tab">
                <input type="radio" id="tab-1b" name="tab-group-2" hidden checked />
                <label class="tabLabel" for="tab-1b">Headers</label>
                <div class="content">
                    <div id="headers"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab">
                <input type="radio" id="tab-2b" name="tab-group-2" hidden checked />
                <label class="tabLabel" for="tab-2b">Body content</label>
                <div class="content">
                    <button id="clipboard" style="display: none;">Copy to clipboard</button>
                    <br/>
                    <div id="bodyContent"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab">
                <input type="radio" id="tab-3b" name="tab-group-2" hidden checked />
                <label class="tabLabel" for="tab-3b" id="statusListItem">Status</label>
                <div class="content">
                    <div id="status"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right w30">
        <div class="center">
                <h2>History</h2>

            <table id="historyContainer"></table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css ..

```
.left {
    float: left;
}
.right {
    float: right;
}
.center {
    text-align: center;
}
.w30 {
    width: 30%;
}
.w40 {
    width: 40%;
}
.w50 {
    width: 50%;
}
.w60 {
    width: 60%;
}
.w100 {
    width: 100%;
}
.bCollapse {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
/*
 * Tabs
 */
 .tabs {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    clear: both;
    margin: 35px 0 25px;
}
.tab {
    float: left;
}
.tabLabel {
    background: #eee;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-left: -1px;
    position: relative;
    left: 1px;
    top: -20px;
}
.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    opacity: 0;
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label {
    background: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    z-index: 2;
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `min-height` for `tabs` **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pgzt6nbf/1/)**

```
 .tabs {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
     min-height: 200px; 
    clear: both;
    margin: 35px 0 25px;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: the only problem is if I add ~10 headers to the request tab contents, they grow over the response area?

Comment: this code will result like this only becoz, the tab label and content were placed in a common div, so the spacing be there if you use relative instead of absolute.. i would suggest better try for some other code or try with js

Answer (score 0):

I remember a year or 2 back, before I learned JS, when I was heavily invested in creating functioning tabs using only HTML and CSS. They can be done, but at a cost of being unable to use animations on them (you cannot animate from display: none to display: block).
Anyway, the issue you are having if because your element with the class "content" has its position set to "absolute". By definition, you are telling this element to not consume space. Remove this, or change the position to "relative", and you should see a more desired behaviour.